# How to loop with multiple *ngFor with different div - Angular 5

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have response with this json hierarchy (content -> categories -> items) the content contains object of categories and each categories contains object of items. So I tried this:

```
<div *ngFor="let content of data">
    <span>{{content.name}}</span>
    <div *ngFor="let category of content.categories">
        <span>.....</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of category.items">
    <span>{{item.type}}</span> //this item is undefined because it is out of category looping div
</div>
```

Comment: ..and the problem is? Why don't you move it inside then?

Comment: are you asking or something? what is your concerns though

Comment: I have updated my answer, just have a look into in that

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with the ngfor outside of the nested fors? from what you described you don't have a `categories` object, just a `content.categories`. so what is in there that you want to see that you can't place it within the loop?

Comment: since `content.categories` is also an array, and `category` is a reference to one of its elements in each loop, which instance or element of the `content.categories` array would you like to iterate through in the `<div *ngFor="let item of category.items">...</div>` loop?

Comment: In the seconde div you want the list of every items of each category ?

Answer (score 3):

The scope of `*ngFor` object is inside closing tag not outside of that so for achieve this you can use **ng-template**

you can do like this,

```
<ng-template let-content ngFor [ngForOf]="data">

   <span>{{content.name}}</span>
   <ng-template let-category ngFor [ngForOf]="content.categories">
      <span>{{category.name}}</span>

      <div *ngFor="let item of category.items">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>

</ng-template>
```

and in `.ts`

```
data = [{
     categories: [{
       name: 'xyz',
        items: [{
          name: 'item1'
        }]
     }]
   }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of post in @Teun I think you want:

```
<div *ngFor="let content of data">
  <span>{{content.name}}</span>
  <div *ngFor="let category of content.categories">
    <span (click)="selectedCategory = category">.....</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedCategory !== undefined">
  <div *ngFor="let item of selectedCategory">
    <span>{{item.type}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the for loop of the items also inside the div looping through the categories. If you want this div to be outside of the category, then you have to make more loops there as well.

```
<div *ngFor="let content of data">
    <span>{{content.name}}</span>
    <div *ngFor="let category of content.categories">
        <span>.....</span>    
         <div *ngFor="let item of category.items">
               <span>{{item.type}}</span> //this item is undefined because it is out of category looping div
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Categories outside of the other loops:

```
<div *ngFor="let content of data">
  <span>{{content.name}}</span>
  <div *ngFor="let category of content.categories">
    <span>.....</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let content of data">
  <div *ngFor="let category of content.categories">
    <div *ngFor="let item of category.items">
      <span>{{item.type}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it outside, I know that it will be fine if it is inside